# Not an enclosing class error Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I am new in android development and do not have an in depth knowledge of Java. I am stuck on a problem for a long time. I am trying to open a new activity on button click. But I am getting an error that **error: not an enclosing class: Katra_home**.

Here is the code for MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bhawan1);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Katra_home.this, Katra_home.class);
            Katra_home.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

And this is the code for Katra_home.java

```
public class Katra_home extends BaseActivity {

protected static final float MAX_TEXT_SCALE_DELTA = 0.3f;

private ViewPager mPager;
private NavigationAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private int mFlexibleSpaceHeight;
private int mTabHeight;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.katra_home);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

Though I have seen many answers on stackoverflow but I could not understand them as I am new in android development. So I would like to ask what changes do I need to make in my code to make it work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It should be

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Katra_home.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

You have to use existing activity context to start new activity, new activity is not created yet, and you cannot use its context or call methods upon it.

*not an enclosing class* error is thrown because of your usage of `this` keyword. `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. With `this` you can only refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor.

`Katra_home.this` is invalid construct

Answer (score 7):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Katra_home.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

This Should the perfect one :)

Answer (score 2):

you are calling the context of not existing activity...so just replace your code in `onClick(View v)` as

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Katra_home.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

it will definitely works....

Answer (score 1):

```
String user_email = email.getText().toString().trim();
firebaseAuth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,user_password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(RegistraionActivity.this, "Registration sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivities(new Intent(RegistraionActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(RegistraionActivity.this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why/how this code will solve the problem. ty

Answer (score 0):

replace code in onClick() method with this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Katra_home.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Katra_home.class));
```

try this one it will be work