# Access Android SQLite Database created in Main Activity from Second activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-activity, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert values in a SQLite Database created in my main activity, from a second activity called by the main.
The error i get come from the context when creating a new database open helper, saying that "Main activity is not an enclosing class".

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DBOpenHelper tdb;
private SQLiteDatabase sdb;
private ListView mainlist;
private ArrayList<String> al_strings;
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa_strings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tdb.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    tdb = new DBOpenHelper(this, "contacts.db", null, 1);
    sdb = tdb.getWritableDatabase();

    String table_name = "contacts";
    String[] columns = {"FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME"};
    String where = null;
    String where_args[] = null;
    String group_by = null;
    String having = null;
    String order_by = null;

    Cursor c = sdb.query(table_name, columns, where, where_args, group_by, having, order_by);

    mainlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
    al_strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    c.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        al_strings.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    aa_strings = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al_strings);
    mainlist.setAdapter(aa_strings);


}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
private DBOpenHelper tdb;
private SQLiteDatabase sdb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText first_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_first_name);
            EditText last_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_last_name);
            EditText home_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_phone);
            EditText mobile_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile_phone);
            EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);

            tdb = new DBOpenHelper(MainActivity.this, "contacts.db", null, 1);
            sdb = tdb.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("FIRST_NAME", first_name.getText().toString());
            cv.put("LAST_NAME", last_name.getText().toString());
            cv.put("HOME_PHONE", home_phone.getText().toString());
            cv.put("MOBILE_PHONE", mobile_phone.getText().toString());
            cv.put("EMAIL", email.getText().toString());
            sdb.insert("contacts", null, cv);
            al_strings.add(first_name.getText().toString() + " " + last_name.getText().toString());
            aa_strings.notifyDataSetChanged();
            finish();
        }
    });




    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not an enclosing class error Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104476/not-an-enclosing-class-error-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you have used MainActivity as context

```
 tdb = new DBOpenHelper(MainActivity.this, "contacts.db", null, 1);
```

In you DBOpenHelper class contructor param should be Context and you should pass

```
 tdb = new DBOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(), "contacts.db", null, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work with getApplicationContext() !

Answer (score 0):

write this in your second activity
    db = new DBOpenHelper(this, "contacts.db", null, 1);

Comment: 'this ' wont work since, this refers to the OnClickListener

Comment: I get another error, saying that the DBOpenhelper cannot be applied to the context, as it is an "anonymous...view.view.OnClickListener"

Comment: then make it `SecondActivity.this`

Answer (score 0):

**A Suggestion :**

Create A Separate Class For Database Actions, For Example `SQLiteHelper.class` Where all the Database Methods like insertion, deletion and Initialization are done, then call this class in any activity by passing context of this activity for example

```
SQLiteHelper sqh = new SQLiteHelper(con);
```

Call the required Methods multiple times from single class.

```
sqh.InsertIntoContacts(values);
```

Comment: My "DBOpenhelper" is already a separated class for database actions. In fact i cannot create a new helper, getting an error with the context parameter.

Comment: then in "DBOpenHelper" make database Methods there, and call them from any activity like myDBOpenhelper.Insert(values);

Comment: Secondly for context, In Activity Make Context variable Global, initialize it on onCreate of the activity like mContext = con, and use this mContext in DBOpenHelper(mContext , "contacts.db", null, 1);

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity,

Declare an object of the Context as,

`Context context = this`;

and instead of

`tdb = new DBOpenHelper(MainActivity.this, "contacts.db", null, 1);`

instead of this, use like this

`tdb = new DBOpenHelper(context, "contacts.db", null, 1);`

This may solve your issue. I didn't test it though. Let me know the status also