# How can I reference the same class variable in different classes?

Tags: java, android

I have a variable "wl" of type "PowerManager.WakeLock". I need to use the same "wl" variable and not a different object in different classes. Can this be done?

```
 public PowerManager.WakeLock wl; 
 // This variable needs to be used like a switch in other classes. 
 // In one class its turned on, in another class I need to call 
 // a method .Release(), to turn it off, 
 // but it has to refer to that same "wl" variable.
```

NotificationReceiver CLass - "holds the power manager

```
     public class NotificationReceiver extends Service {
public PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) 
      getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
public static PowerManager.WakeLock wl = 
       powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, 
       "My:WakelockTag"); //Non-static field 'powerManager' cannot be referenced from a static context


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    wl.acquire();


    return START_NOT_STICKY;

}

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

MainActivity class that I need to use the that variable in

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ExampleService.class);

            startService(serviceIntent);





            NotificationReceiver nn = new NotificationReceiver();// Here I make a new object to access the .aquire() method 

            nn.wl.acquire();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by making your variable static. You can access it by ClassName.variable. (It will be field of only one class, but it can be accessed from all your classes)

Comment: This is not correct. Static variables are common to all instances of the same class not different classes.

Comment: Yes, but author wanted one instance, he could use in all of his classes (well, I understand it this way) and if he make it public he can use ClassName.variable to get acces to it.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil Yes. Thats what I thought.

Comment: @krymus42 I see. Sorry didn't think that through. Yes that can be done. I think you must elaborate that in your answer as well. But it is up to you.

Comment: @LinS Yes but what krymus42 is trying to say is that you can access a class public static variable anywhere using the syntax **ClassName.variableName**. where ClassName is the name of the class where you declare your static variable

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil getting a -.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire()' on a null object reference error

Comment: I tried  public static  PowerManager.WakeLock wl; Then in the other class -  NotificationReceiver nn = new NotificationReceiver();

                nn.wl.acquire();

Comment: No no. You must assign it a value right after declaration.

Comment: @LinS That's because you haven't initialised `wl` itself where you created it. It is null  and that is why you get **null pointer error**.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil I cant have it static. getting a Non-static field 'powerManager' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @LinS can you paste your code. What does it has to do with `wl`. It is totally different question. Because you haven't mentioned anything about `powerManger` and how are you using it in your question, answering it would be just guessing instead. Anyways just for the reference "A static method cannot directly access a non-static variable"

Comment: @LinS Sorry for a late answer. I hope you have solved your issue by now but if not this is the case, the variable `wl` is static and `powerManager` is non-static. So you can't use a non-static variable to initialise a static variable. Because static variables are created when class is loaded into memory, not when a class is instantiated. So `powerManger` doesn't exists when `wl` is created. Your best bet would be to make `powerManager` also static if it doesn't clashes with the rest of your code. If that doesn't work then you might need to look at iluxa'a answer about the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You pass it in either when you construct the class, or in the individual functions that use it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `Singleton` pattern:

```
class LockHolder {

  public static final LockHolder INSTANCE = new LockHolder();

  private final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

  // constructor is private so that noone can create new instances
  private LockHolder() { 
    this.wakeLock = new WakeLock();
  }

  // accessor method is safer than exposing the variable itself;
  // you may eventually end up doing more things here
  public PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock() {
    return wakeLock;
  }
}
```

`LockHolder` is a `Singleton` since only one instance of this class exists.

You use it as follows:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock lock = LockHolder.INSTANCE.wakeLock();
```

Comment: Trying to use your suggestion but getting -"'android.os.PowerManager' is not an enclosing class" the constructor is throwing this. Also dont you mean "private LockHolder() for the constructor? Since thats the name of the class you gave? Thanks

Comment: you're right re `LockHolder`, thanks! corrected the code. As for `not an enclosing class`, that's a separate problem, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104476/not-an-enclosing-class-error-android-studio