# Error: Not an enclosing class - MainActivity

Tags: android

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.lactivity_main);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

}

class Logoutluncher  extends Thread{

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        sleep(1000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);


}
```

}

Comment: Please read the tag description of `javascript`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please specify the exact error that you are facing. Also, mention the error message along with the stack trace if possible.

Comment: my error message that i faced is ( error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity ) ,

Comment: the error in that line (        }Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: Have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104476/not-an-enclosing-class-error-android-studio/31104517

Comment: yes and i still facing the same error at this line ( Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

Using MainActivity.this is referring to the object MainActivity as if it were the current object but the current object is of type Logoutluncher.

Translating "not an enclosing class" would be "not an engaging class" .

To have MainActivity.this valid within the Logoutluncher class, MainActivity must "wrap" the Logoutluncher class, in Logoutluncher must be an inner MainActivity class.

Comment: i am kind of new in this , can you provide me with the correct code ?